# iOS RXSwift4 Cannot invoke 'bind' with an argument list of type '(to: PublishRelay<Void>)'

Tags: swift4, ios11, rx-swift

I'm getting a cryptic message from the compiler, and am trying to debug it, since this code worked on one of teammate's machines. Are we using different versions of RXSwift?

**How can I bind a UIButton.rx to a PublishRelay of type Void ?**

```
import SnapKit
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa


var startButton: UIButton
var tapStartButtonRelay: PublishRelay<Void>

startButton.rx.tap
           .bind(to: tapStartButtonRelay)
//get Cannot invoke 'bind' with an argument list of type '(to: PublishRelay<Void>)'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Issue

It seems you are using an outdated version of **RxSwift**. The code is correct, it works on my machine using **RxSwift 4.2.0**.

### Solution

Please update to **RxSwift 4.2.0** because it contains this [PR](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/pull/1470), where the Rx Team added the `bind(to:)` methods for `PublishRelay` and `BehaviorRelay`.

Comment: Why `bind(to:) ` is only `PublishRelay` and `BehaviorRelay ` & why it's not there for `Observable<T>`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `tapStartButtonRelay.asObserver()`.

Best would be to avoid the subject completely and bind directly to the thing that the button affects.

Comment: Why does `PublishRelay<Void>` not really make sense? Filtering out `error` and `completed` events for UI related events is sometimes the general approach.

Comment: My mistake, I was thinking about `BehaviorRelay` which is what wouldn't make sense. I'll fix the error.